# Autoprefixer command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, autoprefixer

I have a problem using [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) 
I tried installing using:

```
npm install -g autoprefixer
```

and I tried installing it in my project only:

```
npm install autoprefixer --save-dev
```

but nothing seems to help. Every time I get ther error:

```
-bash: autoprefixer: command not found
```

I am using OSX Yosemite, node v4.1.1 and npm v3.3.4.

Note that I am not trying to use Autoprefixer for Gulp or Grunt, I am trying to make a setup where it would run as a npm script (as mentioned [here](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)).

If you need any additional info just ask, I will provide anything needed. This is just frustrating I spent 2 hours trying to fix it but without any luck.

Thanks for all smart answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cli tool for autoprefixer was deprecated.
There's still a seperate package providing it though.

You can use the postcss-cli to run Autoprefixer from CLI:

```
npm install --global postcss-cli autoprefixer
postcss --use autoprefixer *.css -d build/
```

See postcss -h for help.

Comment: I can't install the package postcss-cli. Failed to parse json

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error when I installed first -

```
npm install postcss-cli --save-dev
```

after installing when I ran this command -

```
postcss --use autoprefixer -o css/output.css css/main.css
```

I was getting this error -

> bash: postcss: command not found

So then I tried running globally -

```
npm install --global postcss-cli autoprefixer
```

There was some peer dependencies I installed after that - postcss & postcss-reporter

and finally I run this command of postcss:

> postcss --use autoprefixer -o css/output.css css/main.css

and it's worked. I hope this is helpful